# How to proof that $\mathcal{P}(X)_{\tau}=\mathcal{P}(X)$ on the measure space $(X,\mathcal{P}(X))$

Tags: measure-theory

How to proof that $\mathcal{P}(X)_{\tau}=\mathcal{P}(X)$ on the measure space $(X,\mathcal{P}(X))$ when $\tau$ is the counting measure.

My teacher has defined:
$$\mathbb{N}_{\tau}=\{N\subseteq X\; |\; \text{there exist }P\in\mathcal{P}(X)\;\text{so}\;N\subseteq P\;\;\text{and}\;\tau(P)=0\},$$
where I see that $\mathbb{N}_{\tau}=\{\emptyset\}$, but I don't know how to understand in terms of the Powerset.

I only seem to understand this intuitively, as if $\mathcal{P}(X)$ contain all subsets of $X$, and $\tau$ can be defined on all of the subsets, they must be equal to each other.

I have hard time understanding what my professor would like us to use in this scenario - I thought about defining $\mathcal{P}(X)$ as point masses, however, I have to show that they contain the same sets.

Any help proofing this, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @saz Sorry, I forgot that - I have updated my question.

Comment: the notation $\mathcal P(X)_\tau$ I guess it mean the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\tau$, right? In this case it is enough to show that every subset of $X$ is measurable in the counting measure

Comment: Well, the definition of $\mathcal{P}(X)_{\tau}$ is still missing but probably you define $\mathcal{P}(X)_{\tau} := \sigma(\mathcal{P}(X),\mathbb{N}_{\tau})$. You write that you know that $\mathbb{N}_{\tau} = \{\emptyset\}$... so what exactly do you not understand? If you know this, the assertion is immediate from the definition...

Comment: @saz Sorry for the confusion in the question - I don't know how this can shown in any other way than intuitively.

Comment: Thank you @Masacroso. You are right, it is the enlargement with respect to $\tau$ (if I understand the idea of enlargement correctly).